# Karate run through mvn terminal - Nashorn is null

Tags: karate

I have a karate 0.9.9.RC3 project with Java 15, tests run correctly if running directly through runner, however if I chose to run through 'mvn test' I get 'nashorn is null' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have multiple dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. Follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue